# Scaffolding failed when trying to add "IDENTITY" after checking "override all files" and ApplicationDbContext added in asp.net 6

Tags: c#, model-view-controller

To add identity in my mvc project,

1 - I did right-click on my web project -> hover on 'Add' -> click on 'Add New scaffolded Item'

2 - Select 'Identity' -> click on 'Add'

3 - After loading, I checked on 'Override all files' -> in Data context class, I selected
ApplicationDbContext(BulkyBook.DataAccess) -> Then click on 'Add'

4 - Consequently an error message pops up as:
"There as an error running the selected code generator:
'Scaffolding failed.
Could not load information for project
C:\Users\Owner\source\repos\RentalMovieApp\BulkyBook.Models\BulkyBook.Models.csproj'

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: could you please clarify a few points.
1. have you run a migration, and created and then updated your database with the identity tables.
2. what does your Context class look like? are you inheriting from IdentityContext?

Answer (score 0):

I think I was able to figure out a workaround for this bug on the
`CodeGeneration.Design` tool. What I have gathered after a few tests on the workflow is that the tool (CodeGenerator.Design) seems to only work when you run it from within the same project the Context class lives in.

Essentially, if you add the Scaffolding item and follow the workflow, you will be able to generate the Area folder, which will contain the Data -> AppDbContext, and the Pages folder, Manage folder, and it's corresponding pages. see below image for the structure.

[image]

**Steps to create the identity scaffolding**

1. Right click on the main project
2. Click on the `Add New Scaffold Item`
3. On the dialog box presented, under `Common` look for `Identity`
4. Click add, then select the from the following options: layout, and pages to override.
5. For the data context class, click on the `+` symbol
6. Click on `Add` button

**A few points to note**

- this is a workaround but what could be possible is to move the context to a different project, in order to comply with separation of concern, once you are able to generate the above structure.
- it seems to me that the point point is on step 6, because the CodeGenerator.Design is having a challenge connecting the dots between the main project and the data layer project in your case `BulkyBook.DataAccess`

Answer (score 0):

I was getting the same error when the version of one of my packages was different than the other. So I updated the version of every package to be same (For me it was 7.0.12) and this fixed the issue.

Follow the below steps to update the packages version:

1. Right click on your project file and go to "Manage NuGet Packages..."
2. Select each project update their version, but keep the version same for all packages except the "Microsoft.VisualStudio.Web.CodeGeneration.Design" package

[image: Manage Packages screenshot]